# WCF - Using [MessageContract] without [MessageHeader]

Tags: wcf, messagecontract, datacontracts

The question is pretty straightforward. Is there any sense to use [MessageContract] attribute instead of [DataContract] if we're not using [MessageHeader] attrribute, but only [MessageBodyMember]. In that case it will be the same to use [DataContract] with [DataMember]'s?

Answer (score 1):

`MessageContract` provides extended soap message control. If you want create special message format you should use it, otherwise use `DataContract`